# Python - Multiprocessing Pool Class: Can the Thread Function contain arguments?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool

I want to know if it is possible to pass arguments into the threading pool funktion?

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

def mainFunc():
    myArray = ["A", "B", "C"]

    pool = ThreadPool(8) 
    pool.map(threadFunc, myArray)   # how is it possible to give >>threadFunc<< another argument >>text1<<
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def threadFunc(text2):
    text1 = "Hello "                # this should be given as a argument  of the function
    print text1 + text2

mainFunc()
```

This is a simple example of what i want to do.. How can I give text1 as a second argument to the threadFunc function?

**Solved:**

I  solved the problem with a simple global accessible variable ... but it was only a solution for the problem I had right now ... it is a greater idea to use the `multiprocessing.Process` instead ...

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

this = sys.modules[__name__] 

def mainFunc():
    myArray = ["A", "B", "C"]
    this.text1 = "Hello "

    pool = ThreadPool(8) 
    pool.map(threadFunc, myArray)   # how is it possible to give >>threadFunc<< another argument >>text1<<
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def threadFunc(text2):
    print this.text1 + text2

mainFunc()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The official python docs says

   > A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.

   Therefore it is impossible to add another argument, but you can always add text1 as the last element of your `myArray` and pop it out once you use it.
2. You can also use `multiprocessing.Process` other than pool. In this case you can add another argument easily.

   ```
   def f(name):
       print 'hello', name

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
       p.start()
       p.join()
   ```

Comment: 1. only a good idea if the text1 variable is as simple like "Hello ".. 2. would be the best idea to solve this problem - Thanks a lot - D0N

Comment: @Don  Python iterable list can contain different types values, for example. `text1` can be a String or self-defined Class object or json when other items of myArray are integers:)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as many arguments as you want in a tuple or a list:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

def mainFunc():
    myArray = ["A", "B", "C"]
    text1 = "Hello "

    pool = ThreadPool(8)

    # combine text1 with each element in myArray
    args_generator = ((text1, x) for x in myArray)

    pool.map(threadFunc, args_generator)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def threadFunc(args):
    # unpack arguments
    text1, text2 = args
    print text1 + text2
```